# find a substring in a selected portion of a list elements

Tags: python, string, list, list-comprehension, python-3.5

I have the below string list (list1) and I want to find if str `b` is present anywhere in left hand side portion of an element before the decimal in list1.

I tried the below code but it finds all the elements where str b is found.

```
list1= ['4.39', '5.25', '2.29', '3.16', '4.19', '1.5', '4.17', '2.18', '5.18', '4.18', '5.16', '4.4']
b=str(1)
print([s for s in list1 if b in s])
```

it returns the following:

```
['3.16', '4.19', '1.5', '4.17', '2.18', '5.18', '4.18', '5.16']
```

However, I want to get only `1.5` because this is the only element where string b matches the left hand side part before decimal. Remember the elements are in string format. Any fast way of checking this thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split each string by `.` and extract the first split:

```
print([s for s in list1 if '1' in s.split('.')[0]])

['1.5']
```

For a precise match, use `==`:

```
print([s for s in list1 if s.split('.')[0] == '1'])

['1.5']
```

Comment: And do you know how could i find the actual index of matched element in list1?

Comment: `[idx for idx, s in enumerate(list1) if '1' in s.split('.')[0]]` should do it.

Comment: Thank you jpp. it works fine. Just a small comment, there seems to be a small typo in the code. There is one additional bracket by mistake after [0] in the split s.split('.')[0])

Comment: @HT121, I think it should be fine, there are 2 square open brackets and 2 closing ones? I edited it to make a list comprehension earlier (you may wish to refresh).